# How to host create-react-app-2 build on IIS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iis, webpack, create-react-app

I'm trying to host a React.js application, created with create-react-app (react-scripts v2.1.5), on IIS.

I keep getting the following type errors:

[image: browser console output]

---

I've tried everything mentioned in this question, to no avail:
[create-react-app on IIS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823797/create-react-app-on-iis-10)

Hosting it with "serve -s build" as suggested by CRA's build script works fine, but I want to host it through IIS.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try dropping your build folder onto your web host?

Comment: Do you mean to copy it to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot"? Did that, made not difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution was to add "homepage": "." to my project's package.json file.

Here are some links for further information:

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1487

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1480

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1094

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/1489

Comment: Just to provide more context, the issue I was encountering was because my project was not hosted at the root, but under an alias. That's why I had to add the homepage setting to specify a relative path to resources.