# React Deployment on IIS server

Tags: reactjs, iis, deployment

I would like to deploy my react app to IIS and I tried a step by step guide.

I already tried a create-react-app and I already added a new website but when I run It says:

> this site can't reach

.

I tried that way but some steps are not understood.=>[create-react-app on IIS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823797/create-react-app-on-iis-10)

I am newbie and May I know step by step if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you could try belwo steps to host a reasct app on the IIS.

If you don't have the react app, I suggest you could install the [npm](https://nodejs.org/en/)  and generate a react app for testing.

1.Open cmd and locate a folder by using cd yourfoldername

[image]

2.Run below command to add the package

```
npm i -g create-react-app
```

3.Run below command to create the react app in the folder, wait for creating the application

```
create-react-app my-app
```

[image]

4. Build the project to production folder.

   npm run build

[image]

5.Open IIS management console and create a new web sites and use the build path as the physical path. for example: `D:\ReactAppTest\my-app\build`

Notice: You should pay attention to your port number.

[image]

6. Then you could use that port number to access your react application. For example:
   http://localhost:9965/

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this way on yesterday and its worked. So I will mark as the answer.