# I am trying to host a React application in IIS

Tags: reactjs, iis

I am trying to host a React application in IIS in Windows Server 2022 Standard. So below are the steps which I did:

1. `npm run build` - I executed this command inside my code to get the build folder.
2. Next I created a folder `exlibris` inside `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`. The `wwwroot` folder already contains an `iisstart.html` and `iisstart.png`.
3. Then I copied all the contents of the build folder inside `exlibris`. So the path for the exlibris apps path look like this `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\exlibris`.
4. Using the IIS Manager under the `Sites > Default Web Site` I clicked on `Add Application`. The following values were chosen `Alias: exlibris`, `Physical Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\exlibris`.
5. Then when I go to browser and type in `localhost/exlibris` nothing shows up. Upon doing `inspect` it shows under the `Elements` tab `<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>`. I already have Javascript enabled on the browser.

**Options Tried**

6. When I put the contents of my build folder in the path `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\` instead of the directory `exlibris` the application runs.
7. If I put the default pages provided by IIS `iisstart.html` and `iisstart.png` inside the path `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\exlibris` the browser shows the IIS landing page on the url `localhost/exlibris` without problem.

I am new to deploying React or any JS application in IIS.
How to fix this problem any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Deployment on IIS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58057981/react-deployment-on-iis-server)

Comment: No, they are adding a website but what I want to do it to use path under localhost to host my website. I kind of figured out the problem which requires a different solution. The problem is with the static folders produced by the `npm run build`. If I put the static folder inside /exlibris then it cannot find the the files to display the application. If I put the `static` folder inside `exlibris` then the website is not longer displayed. It has something to do how IIS handles static folders of the applications.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using the below solution

After the app was build and put inside the path `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\exlibris` open up the index.html file which was created by the `npm run build` command. It will look like somewhat below and add the folder name in front of all the `static files` path.
For example in my case:
`<script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.47b5a360.js">` needs changing to
`<script defer="defer" src="/exlibris/static/js/main.47b5a360.js">`.
P.S: Please do that for all the paths. I do not know how to do it using relative paths in IIS so I went inside and changed to absolute paths inside the `index.html` folder. Now when I do `localhost/exlibris` my application shows up.